# C++ - Injecting code into running process (using DLL)

Tags: java, c++, dll-injection

I am trying to change the value of an int in a running java process using Dll injection.

My Dll:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <jni.h>

using namespace std;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDLL, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    HMODULE m_hDllInstance = LoadLibrary("jvm.dll");
    if( m_hDllInstance == 0)
    {
        cout << "The jvm.dll could not be found" << endl;
        getchar();
    }
    else
        cout << "jvm.dll found" << endl;


    JavaVM *jvm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    typedef jint (JNICALL * GetCreatedJavaVMs)(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
    GetCreatedJavaVMs jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs = (GetCreatedJavaVMs)GetProcAddress(m_hDllInstance, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs");

    jint size = 1;
    jint vmCount;

    jint ret= jni_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&jvm, size, &vmCount);

    cout << endl << "GetCreated: " << vmCount << endl;
    getchar();

    jint rc = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **) & env, NULL);

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/InjectMe");
    jfieldID field = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "prefix", "I");
    jint integer = 1;
    env->SetIntField(cls, field, integer);

    return TRUE;
}
```

The java class:

```
package com;

public class InjectMe 
{
    static int prefix = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(prefix + ": " + s);

            if(prefix == 1)
                break;
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

When I call `GetLastError()` in the Dll injector, I get 0, so I have not posted the code to it.

When I run the following code, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since `prefix` is a static variable, you need to use the proper function:

```
env->SetStaticIntField(cls, field, integer);
```

And at the start of `DllMain()` you might want to add something like this as well, so all of it isn't done more than once:

```
if( Reason!=DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH ) return TRUE;
```

And at the end, for proper cleanup:

```
jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```